# Both images are moving

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to put two images beside each other by using

```css
span.img {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 100px;
  transition: margin 0.5s;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
}
span.img:hover {
  margin-left: 0px;
}
span.image {
  margin-left: 350px;
  transition: margin 0.5s;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
}
span.image:hover {
  margin-left: 450px;
}
```

```html
<span>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200/FF6347/FFF" />
</span>
<span>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200/47E3FF/000" />
</span>
```

and I want to move the one on the left on mouse hover (by transition in css), but the problem is when I try to do so, the image on the right hand will also move.

How can I make the right side image don't move when the other image is moving?

Comment: We can't really help you without all of your code.

Comment: Please create a working example of your code. And FYI `<img>` is a self closing tag and don't need `</img>`.

Comment: you can use [codepen](http://codepen.io/pen/) to illustrate your problem.

Comment: Add a working sample to get a quick solution..

Comment: Great, now just your CSS, please. :)

Answer (score 2):

How about css transforms? [Translations](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-transforms-1/#transform-rendering) in particular. A css transform does not affect the reserved space in the layout, keeping all other objects where they belong. Be warned though, a transformed object **does** recieve pointer events on its visual location. Another point is that it can cause scrollbars to appear unless an element higher in the hierarchy has `overflow: hidden`.

```css
span.image {
  /* Inline block causes width and height to affect the span element. */
  display:inline-block;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
}
span.image img{
  transition:transform 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transform: translate(0,0);
  /* Hovering over the image causes the transition to take effect.*/
  /* This can cause weird bouncing effects. As such ignore pointer events.*/
  pointer-events:none !important;
  
}
span.image:hover img {
  transform: translate(350px, 0);
}
```

```html
<span class="image">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200/FF6347/FFF" />
</span>
<span class="image">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200/47E3FF/000" />
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add differend `id`s or `class`es to your `span` tags and write different animations. This should solve your problem.

Comment: This is really a generic 'you should try this' that would have suited better as a comment. Since we don't know OP's code, we can't know for sure this solves it.

Comment: Actually, this would be solution, probably. :)

Comment: @sinisake, as I expected)

Answer (score 0):

Try using bootstrap div. 
Here's the code:

```
<div class = "container">
    < div class = "row">
       <div class = "col-md-6"> //you can use anyone here

              insert image
```

Comment: Really no need for bootstrap here.